# INSERT or UPDATE mysql, php

Tags: php, mysql

Не знаю как реализовать данную задачу(таблица cron_planning_figure):
[image]

Имеется вот такой вид таблицы. Я написал скрипт который будет делать запрос(собирать все то что вы видите на скриншоте) а затем он должен делать INSERT в таблицу либо же UPDATE.

Скрипт будет запускаться кроном несколько раз в день. Работать будет все следующим образом: Это статистика людей за текущий месяц(в моем случае за январь, день и время мне не важно, главное чтобы был год и месяц, но для удобства я храню время в timestamp).

Апдейт будет в том случае. когда поле fact меняется, а оно будет меняться постоянно, поле work_days, каждый день будет +1, ну и поле month_year(это простой timestamp).

А инсерт будет делаться только в двух случаях, если начался новый месяц и если появился новый пользователь( в нашем случае их всего 7, завтра может быть уже 8). Когда наступит февраль то там появится опять 7 записей(может больше, если кто-то из новеньких будет).

Смотрел в сторону INSERT ODKU - не особо мне подходит. Может как-то с помощью пыха такое реализовать? Спасибо за внимание. немного запутанная задача.тяжело объяснить

Подытожим:

INSERT - наступает новый месяц. Появилась новая строка в таблице(должна вставиться новая строка с новым user_id)

UPDATE - при изменение полей (plan,fact,work_days)

Спасибо за внимание!

Выкладываю код на всякий случай, были попытки что-то сделать, но пока не пойму логику(знаю прекрасно что лучше mysqli или pdo, но сейчас не об этом):

```
include_once (dirname(__DIR__).'/application/config.php');

$values = array();
$array = array();

$sql_request = "
      SELECT 
        r.userId as user_id,
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as month_year,
        (SELECT spf.plan_value FROM settings_planning_figure AS spf WHERE DATE_FORMAT(spf.month,'%Y-%m') = '2019-01' AND spf.role = u.rules) AS plan,
        CAST(AVG(
          CASE
            WHEN r.reject_date IS NULL AND DATE_FORMAT(r.date_add, '%Y-%m') = '2019-01' THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,r.date_add,r.approve_date)
            WHEN r.approve_date IS NULL AND DATE_FORMAT(r.date_add, '%Y-%m') = '2019-01' THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,r.date_add,r.reject_date)
          END) AS DECIMAL(10,1)) AS fact,
        (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM (
            SELECT *
            FROM log_user_activity AS lua
            WHERE lua.user_id IN
               (SELECT u.id FROM users AS u WHERE u.rules IN ('21','25','29') AND 
                  u.block_status = 0 AND 
                  u.id != 120
               ) AND
                DATE_FORMAT(lua.action_date, '%Y-%m') = '2019-01'
                GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(lua.action_date, '%Y-%m-%d'), lua.user_id
               ) AS count_days
         WHERE count_days.user_id = u.id
         GROUP BY userId) AS work_days
      FROM request AS r
      INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.id = r.userId
      WHERE r.userId IN(
              SELECT u.id
              FROM users AS u
              WHERE u.rules IN ('21','25','29') AND u.block_status = 0 AND u.id != 120) AND
              (CAST(r.date_add AS date) = CAST(r.reject_date AS date) OR CAST(r.date_add AS date) = CAST(r.approve_date AS date))
      GROUP BY r.userId";

$sql_cpf = "SELECT * 
            FROM cron_planning_figure as cpf 
            WHERE date_format(cpf.month_year,'%Y-%m') = date_format(CURRENT_DATE,'%Y-%m')";

$query_cpf  = mysql_query($sql_cpf,$connect_db);

while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_cpf)){
    $array['date'] = $result['month_year'];
    $array['user_id'][] = $result['user_id'];
}

$query = mysql_query($sql_request,$connect_db);

while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    $values['string'][] = "('$result[user_id]', '$result[month_year]',
                  '$result[plan]',    '$result[fact]', '$result[work_days]'
                 )";
    $values['user_id'][] = $result['user_id'];
}

if(date('Y-m',strtotime($array['date'])) == date('Y-m') || !empty(array_diff($values['user_id'],$array['user_id']))){
    $sql = "UPDATE";
}
else
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO cron_planning_figure (user_id, month_year, plan, fact, work_days)
            VALUES "  .implode(",",$values['string']);
}

mysql_query($sql, $connect_db);
```

Comment: 1. Можно сделать хранимую процедуру. На вход - данные. Сама процедура решает, что делать - INSERT или UPDATE. Могу накидать примерчик, но будьте добры показать схему. 2. Почему не подходит INSERT ODKU? Сделайте первичный ключ составным: `user_id`, `month_year`, а id удалите.

Comment: @TotalPusher                                                                                                                           По Схеме тут все просто:                                                                                                  create table cron_planning_figure
(
  id         int auto_increment
    primary key,
  user_id    int          null,
  month_year timestamp    null,
  plan       int          null,
  fact       varchar(255) null,
  work_days  int(5)       null
)
  charset = utf8;

Comment: *Смотрел в сторону INSERT ODKU - не особо мне подходит.* Обоснуйте. По описанию задачи он (или REPLACE) - самое то, что нужно.

Comment: @TotalPusher Я видимо плохо разбираюсь в ODKU. А что в моем случае нужно будет писать в ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?

Comment: @TotalPusher *Сделайте первичный ключ составным: user_id, month_year* Не, не подойдёт, у него там, несмотря на имя поля, и день, и время присутствуют (вот нахрен это надо? впрочем, каждый сам себе генератор геморроя). Нужен уникальный индекс по выражению или по вычисляемому полю, где от штампа времени оставлены только год и месяц.\

Comment: Ну в моем случае уникальных полей нет, разве что только month_year меняется, а user_id - это же не уникальное поле. Если наступит февраль, то произойдет инсерт и айдишники будут повторяться

Comment: *в моем случае уникальных полей нет, разве что только month_year меняется, а user_id - это же не уникальное поле.* Но пара (год-месяц, user_id) - она-то уникальна?

Comment: @Akina, да, но каким образом оно будет уникальным если в каждой записи одинаковая дата? Добавиться только одна запись а остальные же нет. так как они будут совпадать с первой записью. или я  не прав? То есть в нашем случае 7 записей с датой 2019-01-23 09:32:02

Comment: Друг мой, сделайте милость, почитайте про составные индексы ХОТЬ ЧТО-НИБУДЬ...

Comment: Весь этот геморрой в том что я делаю что-то типа отчета. Каждый месяц будут видеть статистику за каждый месяц, из-за этого мне эта дата нужна.

Comment: @Akina ок, сделал составной индекс CREATE INDEX date_user ON cron_planning_figure(month_year, user_id). Что дальше?

Comment: *Что дальше?* Обратите внимание на мою фразу "у него там, несмотря на имя поля, и день, и время присутствуют ... Нужен уникальный индекс по выражению или по вычисляемому полю". И измените соотв. образом структуру индекса.

Comment: @Akina CREATE UNIQUE INDEX date_user ON cron_planning_figure(user_id, month_year)

Comment: Да, вот если бы не было дня и времени в поле month_year, проблем бы не было...

Comment: Очеты строятся **динамически**, из исходных данных. А не вносятся в БД как будто огрызком карандаша и ластиком на бумажке. Данные должны вноситься только через insert, а вожделенный отчёт строится по запросу примитивным запросом select

Comment: `ALTER TABLE cron_planning_figure ADD COLUMN year_and_month INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CONCAT(YEAR(month_year), MONTH(month_year))), ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_year_month_user (user_id, year_and_month);`

Comment: @Akina спасибо огромное, выручили. А вообще, подобную задачу можно как-то на PHP сделать? Не применяя ODKU? просто интересно какой алгоритм. По коду я пытался сделать так что делать ИНСЕРТ если появилась новая строка и начался новый месяц, иначе всегда апдейт

Comment: *А вообще, подобную задачу можно как-то на PHP сделать?* Можно. Но зачем решать задачу инструментом, который для решения именно этой задачи не предназначен?

Answer (score 0):

Как всегда, проблема здесь в неверном подходе.

Начиная работать с БД, большинство людей не понимают её динамического характера, и по привычке относятся к ней, как к классному журналу с оценками. В котором единственный способ поменять информацию - это соскрести лезвием и ластиком одну оценку и вписать другую.

#### База данных работает по-другому.

Благодаря гениальному изобретению - языку SQL - можно на практически натуральном английском языке попросить БД построить любые отчеты из исходных данных. Это значит, что не нужно самому подсчитывать промежуточный итог и формировать таблицу так, как она будет выводиться. Надо просто накапливать исходные данные, а отчет будет строиться динамически.

в данном случае надо две таблицы

- в первой хранится юзера, дата и план. одна строка за день.
- во второй хранится юзер, дата и факт. за каждый день столько строк, сколько записей о фактах.

дальше, в запросе SELECT мы применяем магическую функцию sum() для подсчета факта за каждый день, сгруппировав для этого запрос по юзеру и дате.
Количество рабочих дней можно при этом посчитать в пхп, а можно отдельным запросом.

Несмотря на то, что это все кажется запредельно сложным, на самом деле это все примитивные запросы, уровня таблицы умножения. их надо освоить и начать применять БД по назначению.

Comment: Спасибо, на самом деле про это я тоже думал. Самая проблема в том что иногда не знаешь, какую делать структуру для той или иной задачи.

Comment: Насчет структуры - надо читать основы реляционных баз данных, атомарность данных, про Нормальные формы. Со временем это становится рефлексом.